Gradle: "Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:33.3.1-android "?
I'm using Gradle 6.9 (this git project won't build on anything >= Gradle 7 so the Gradle has to be 6.9 or lower). It also failed w/ the same error using Gradle 6.8.3.
Here is the error when I gradle clean build   :
Task :wallet:preDevDebugBuild FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':wallet:preDevDebugBuild'.
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':wallet:devDebugCompileClasspath'.
     Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:33.3.1-android.
     Required by:
         project :wallet
        The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'flavor' with value 'dev', attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr' with value 'Aar'. However we cannot choose between the following variants of com.google.guava:guava:33.3.1-android:
          - androidApiElements
          - jreApiElements
 

I have tried referencing other repositiories in my project level build.gradle. All have failed :
buildscript {
    repositories {
//      mavenLocal()
        //maven { url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
        
        
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
//      mavenLocal()
//      maven { url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}

Here are my (some) subproject dependencies (edited for brevity):
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.bitcoinj:bitcoinj-core:0.16.4'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:33.3.1-android'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava
    //implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:33.4.0-android'

    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.11.0'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.9'
    implementation 'com.github.tony19:logback-android:3.0.0'
}

I know the artifact exists:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/33.3.1-android/
and...
https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/33.3.1-android/versions
Is this a repository problem? Or is it due to me lacking some Gradle skills?

It might be a bug on the cache for your local repository. So my suggestion is to go to your local repository folder and delete the whole com.google.guava folder for it. And if you are using android studio also use the clean cache option (this might take a while, it's been a hot few years I don't develop on android but these errors were always related to local caching).

Jorge, any idea where my "repository folder" is?

fyi: Yes, I was using Android Studio, but am now trying to isolate the problem and staying out of it.  I issue the gradle clean build command at the command prompt rather  than using the AS ide.

Found it:  C:\Users\MyUserHome.m2

Gradle uses its own repo it should be in C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\caches  so if your is using .m2 it likely you have set it to use same as maven

I rebooted then renamed C:\Users<username>.gradle  to
C:\Users<username>\OLD.gradle
but the problem hasn't changed. Great suggestion though. Thanks.

I also renamed C:\Users<username>.m2 to OLD.m2  but still same problem.
"Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:33.3.1-android "

lol, you got rid of the entire repos... Don't rename to top folders (.m2 / .gradle) just the internal ones, for gradle it should be caches for m2 it should be repository (unless you have a custom ones). After that My suggestion is create an empty project with nothing but the dependency to com.google.guava:guava:33.3.1-android see if the same error happens.

I just did this test here on maven and it downloaded this artifact fine.
